# Set disassembly view colors

Tags: eclipse, assembly, eclipse-cdt, code-composer

How can one change the colors used in the disassembly view of TI's Code Composer Studio 6.1.3, that uses Eclipse 4.5 CDT 8.8?

I have selected the Eclipse "Dark theme" but it does not seem to have applied to the disassembly view, nor the memory browser view.. the latter is less of an issue as although the background remains a blazing white, the text colors mean that the content is visible.

However, with the Disassembly view set to show source, most of the source shows as a *very* pale lilac color which is nearly invisible against the white background. Some of flow control statements (e.g. if, else, etc) show in the same red-ish color that they show in the C/C++ editor leading me to believe that the text colors are related to the C/C++ editor settings maybe (?).

In which case the ideal solution, rather than changing the source text color, would be to be able to change the disassembly view's background color from white to something that offered more contrast and also maybe the color of the assembly text also. Is it possible to do this? Or even just change the source text colors independently of the C/C++ editor?

[image: disassembly window]

Comment: looks like a bug to me. have you tried reporting it to TI?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yep I've since asked on the CDT and the TI forum and subsequently added a CDT bug report. I'll answer with the details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also asked this on the Eclipse CDT forum and was informed thusly by Marc Khouzam:

> The Disassembly view and Memory Browser have not been adapted to automatically change colours for the Dark theme.
>
> You can change the colours for the memory browser by going to Preferences->Traditional Memory Rendering.
> I don't think there is a way to change the colours for the Disassembly view though.

So I have added a bug report to the eclipse cdt.debug bug tracker, here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501609 and also raised the matter on the relevant forum at TI.

Comment: This bug recently got a resolution! Fix should be available in CDT 9.8 